# Error Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'addEventListener') in a separeted file

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, addeventlistener

This error keep showing to me only if a put this JavaScript code in a separeted file, and link to my Html... If they are insede a  tag they work just fine...

```
script.js:4 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'addEventListener')
```

Html:

```html
<div class="navbarr__toggle" id="mobile-menu">
                <span class="barr"></span>
                <span class="barr"></span>
                <span class="barr"></span>
            </div>
            <ul class="navbarr__menu">
                <li class="navbarr__item">
                    <a href="#me" class="navbarr__links"><span>01. &nbsp;</span> About me </a>
                </li>
                <li class="navbarr__item">
                    <a href="#work" class="navbarr__links"><span>02. &nbsp;</span> Projects</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
```

JavaScript:

```js
console.log("out of script");
let menu = document.querySelector('#mobile-menu');
let menuLinks = document.querySelector(".navbarr__menu");
menu.addEventListener('click', function(){
    console.log("!I here");
    menu.classList.toggle('is-active');
    menuLinks.classList.toggle('active');
    
})
```

What can be the issue here? note that I alredy link the .Js file to my .Html...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely you have issues with connecting script.js to your html file. You either need to connect js file after `</body>` tag or check if html content is ready/rendered with DOMContentLoaded event inside of your js file, and when DOM content is loaded you can execute your js code. Should be fine then.